# Detect type from string objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, types, type-conversion

Whats the best way of detecting a data type from a string in Objective-c?

I'm importing CSV files but each value is just a string.

E.g. How do I tell that "2.0" is a number, "London" should be treated as a category and that "Monday 2nd June" or "2/6/2012" is a date.

I need to test the datatype some how and be confident about which type I use before passing the data downstream.

Comment: if it's a csv, don't you know something about the columns?  I would expect each column to be consistent on datatype ...

Comment: Yes, the columns should be consistent on datatype, but you dont know anything about the type of those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

----------UPDATE----------
Instead of my previous suggestion, try this:

```
NSString *csvString = @"333";
NSString *charSet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,";
NSScanner *typeScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: csvString];
[typeScanner setCharactersToBeSkipped: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charSet]];
NSString *checkString = [[NSString alloc] init];
[typeScanner scanString:csvString intoString:&checkString];

if([csvString length] == [checkString length]){

    //the string "csvString" is an integer
}
```

To check for other types (float, string, etc.), change this line (which checks for `int` type) `NSString *charSet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,";` to `NSString *charSet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` (which checks for `float` type) or `NSString *charSet = @"1234567890";` (which checks for a string composed only of letters).

-------Initial Post-------

You could do this:

```
NSString *stringToTest = @"123";
NSCharacterSet *intValueSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSArray *test = [stringToTest componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:intValueSet];


if ([test count]==[stringToTest length]+1){

    NSLog(@"It's an int!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"It's not an int");
}
```

This works for numbers that don't have a decimal point or commas as thousands separators, like "8493" and "883292837". I've tested it and it works.

Hope this provides a start for you! I'll try to figure out how to test for numbers with decimal points and strings.

Like Andrew said, regular expressions are probably good for this, but they're a bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks, i'll mark this as the answer. I guess the hardest case is detecting date.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is the only thing I can think about, but if you are on mac or iphone, than you might try e.g. RegexKitLite

Comment: ...or use the built-in `NSRegularExpression`.